# How to change search query in magento?

Tags: magento

I want to replace magento search query with my custom query. I was try in Mysql4/fulltext.php but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Extend Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query and write a function called getSynonymFor() which would look like this:

```
public function getSynonymFor()
{
    //use custom logic to check query text and replace here
    if ($shouldReplace) {
        //find replacement
        return $replacementQuery;
    }
    //otherwise
    return $this->getData('synonym_for');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In

```
app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php
```

change

```
$likeCond = '(' . join(' OR ', $like) . ')';
```

to

```
$likeCond = '(' . join(' AND', $like) . ')';
```

and

```
$where .= ($where ? ' OR ' : '') . $likeCond;
```

to

```
$where .= ($where ? ' AND ' : '') . $likeCond;
```